# What is a good way to do an atomic insert or prevent a race condition on create with Mongoid?

Tags: ruby, mongodb, mongoid

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document

  field :email, type: String

  validates_uniqueness_of email
end
```

Although Mongoid supports [atomic operations](https://docs.mongodb.com/ruby-driver/v2.2/tutorials/6.0.0/mongoid-persistence/#atomic), I do not see one for insert.

Since `User.create` is not atomic, it seems that 2 Users could be created with the same email address simultaneously.

So, what is a good way to ensure that 2 users do not register the same email address simultaneously?

I can see one solution is to use a unique DB index, but are there any other good ways of doing this?